# Minimize the sum of absolute value when subtracted by a constant

Tags: optimization, computational-mathematics

Given an array a with integers $a_1,a_2,a_3,..,a_n$ and an integer c.
Find a permutation $b_1,b_2,b_3,..,b_n$ such that the value of the following expression minimizes:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |b_{i+1}-b_i-c|$$
It came out that if I arrange b in non-decreasing order for c greater than or equal to zero, it minimizes. But I do not have any idea how to prove it (or disprove it). Can someone help me to prove this.

Also I would like to know if something like this holds true for c less than zero.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality